# Unchecking checkbox in angular-material manually

Tags: angular-material, angular2-forms

I have an issue with Angular Material as I am trying to nest select statements and provide a UI for roles selected, with the ability to the remove these roles. [Image1- Selecting from dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pw4x.png), [Image2- Selecting Item in 'Add Additional Roles'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBGIs.png), 
The problem is that when I remove the roles the checkbox is still selected for them in the 'Add Additional Roles' dropdown, which means that when you de-select the form item, the label still shows as the role being checked (when it's actually been removed in the component.ts)
[Image3- Checkbox still shows after role deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfg7G.png), [Image4- Deleted role still shows as the label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0vYR.png)
Is there possibly a way to force a checkbox to be unchecked without actually selecting it? When a user removes an item, I essentially what to be able to manually force that role to be unchecked in the 'Add Additional Roles' dropdown.

I've tried console logging the event on mat-select to see if there is anyway to manually force the checkbox to be checked/unchecked, but can't find any way of doing this.

```
<mat-form-field fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="50" class="md-block u-mat-form-field-padding-0">
                  <mat-label for="siteInfo">Select Roles</mat-label>
                  <mat-select id="siteInfo" formControlName="siteInfo" multiple required>
                    <div style="display:flex; padding:10px; flex-wrap:wrap;">
                      <div style="flex:1 50%; display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
                        <div style="flex:1 100%">
                          <label>Choose Role Group</label>
                          <mat-select
                            id="roleGroupId"
                            formControlName="roleGroupId"
                            multiple
                            required
                            placeholder="Select"
                          >
                            <mat-option
                              *ngFor="let roleGroup of roleGroupList"
                              [value]="{ submitValue: roleGroup.SYS_RoleGroupID, formValue: roleGroup.RoleGroup }"
                              (click)="addOrRemoveRole(roleGroup)"
                              >{{ roleGroup.RoleGroup }}</mat-option
                            >
                          </mat-select>
                        </div>
                        <div style="flex:1 100%">
                          <label for="roleId">Add additional Roles</label>
                          <mat-select
                            id="roleId"
                            formControlName="roleId"
                            multiple
                            required
                            placeholder="select"
                            (keyup)="isRoleIdOrRoleGroup($event)"
                            (click)="isRoleIdOrRoleGroup($event)"
                          >
                            <mat-option
                              *ngFor="let userRole of userRoleList"
                              [value]="{ submitValue: userRole.SYS_RoleID, formValue: userRole.Role }"
                              (click)="addOrRemoveRole($event)"
                              id="{{ userRole.SYS_RoleID }}"
                              >{{ userRole.Role }}</mat-option
                            >
                          </mat-select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div style="flex:1 50%">
                        <p>Current Roles</p>
                        <ul>
                          <li *ngFor="let role of currentRoles" id="{{ role.SYS_RoleID }}">
                            <span>{{ role.Role }}</span
                            ><span style="background:lightblue" (click)="addOrRemoveRole($event)">Remove</span>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>

                      <div style="flex: 0 75%"></div>
                    </div>
                  </mat-select>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="siteInfo.touched && siteInfo.invalid">
                    This field is required
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
```

```
  addOrRemoveRole(selectedRoleOrGroup) {
    // debugger;
    console.log(selectedRoleOrGroup);
    // Check to see if Role Group is being added
    if (selectedRoleOrGroup.SYS_RoleGroupID) {
      // Check to see if user is de-deselecting a Role Group (ie, if roleGroupId already exists, then set it to empty)
      if (this.roleGroupId.value.length === 0) {
        // this needs to change to just splice of rolegroup id items rather than reset selected roles completely
        this.currentRoles = [];
        return (this.userRoleList = this.filterRoles(this.userRoleListMaster, this.currentRoles));
      } else {
        // If they are selecting a role group (ie it's length is 0), then set it with dummy data
        this.currentRoles = this.roleGroupDummyData;
        return (this.userRoleList = this.filterRoles(this.userRoleListMaster, this.currentRoles));
      }
    }

    let selectedUserRole;
    if (selectedRoleOrGroup.srcElement.innerText === 'Remove') {
      selectedUserRole = {
        SYS_RoleID: Number(selectedRoleOrGroup.path[1].id),
        Role: selectedRoleOrGroup.path[1].children[0].innerText
      };
      console.log('SELECTEDUSERROLE: ', selectedUserRole);
    } else {
      selectedUserRole = {
        SYS_RoleID: Number(selectedRoleOrGroup.path[1].id),
        Role: selectedRoleOrGroup.srcElement.innerText
      };
    }

    // Check to see if the role already exists.
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.currentRoles.length; i++) {
      if (selectedUserRole.SYS_RoleID === this.currentRoles[i].SYS_RoleID) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    // If the role already exists then admin must want to remove it, so filter it out
    if (count > 0) {
      this.currentRoles = this.currentRoles.filter(role => role.SYS_RoleID !== selectedUserRole.SYS_RoleID);
    }
    // If the role doesn't exist, then add the role
    else {
      this.currentRoles = [...this.currentRoles, selectedUserRole];
    }
}
```

In the component.ts function above, roles get added/deleted, but as of yet I haven't found a way to be able to manually uncheck the checkbox for when an item is deleted.